# JQuery pseudo selector :visible is working at one place but not at other place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select those input fields on page to validate which are visible on layout. I am able to find out this through one way but with another way its not actually working. What I am getting is my selector is working for direct child but not for grand children.

I want to select only those elements ids which are actually visible on layout to validate them as they should not be blank.

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/themohanahuja/tQHnf/7/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="createdDiv1">
    <div id="row11">
        <div class="hide">
            <input type="text" class="blk" id="inp_11"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row12">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="blk" id="inp_12" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="createdDiv2">
    <div id="row21" class="hide">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="blk" id="inp_21" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row22" class="">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="blk" id="inp_22" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="subCheck('#createdDiv1 :visible')">check 1st</button>
<button onclick="subCheck('#createdDiv2 :visible')">check 2nd</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function subCheck(inBlock) {
    inBlock=(inBlock==undefined)?'':inBlock;
    var ids=[];

    $(inBlock+' .blk').each(function(){
        ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    console.log(ids);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

**Note:** I don't want to change my `subCheck()` function since its generalized for all valiations, what I need to know how can I make it work with `:visible` selector or something similar to it to work with multi-levels checks for visible elements.

**Sorry If I am making it ambiguous for you. I am not sure what exactly to explain in words.**

Comment: What do you aspect that the alert dsplay in the example?

Comment: my alert is showing the element selected, and I want only those element which are visible on layout should come in alert. @IrvinDomininakaEdward

Comment: Have you tried using .is() ? http://jsfiddle.net/rKwCy/

Answer (score 0):

use [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude the class `.hide`:

```
<button onclick="subCheck('#createdDiv1 .inputDiv:not(\'.hide\')')">
    check 1st
</button>
<button onclick="subCheck('#createdDiv2 .inputDiv:not(\'.hide\')')">
    check 2nd
</button>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4PSV/1/

Although I wouldn't suggest using `onclick` at all though, instead:

```
<button class="subcheck" data-id="createdDiv1">check 1st</button>
<button class="subcheck" data-id="createdDiv2">check 2nd</button>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.subcheck' function() {
        //Creates string as: '#createdDiv1 .inputDiv:not('hide')
        var ft = "#" + $(this).data('id') + " .inputDiv:not('.hide')";
        subCheck( ft );
    });
</script>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kY8Wh/

Lastly, if you were wishing to implement your `:visible` then:

```
<button onclick="subCheck('#createdDiv1 .inputDiv:visible')">
    check 1st
</button>
<button onclick="subCheck('#createdDiv2 .inputDiv:visible')">
    check 2nd
</button>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgm78/

Would be sufficient too.

Comment: @DeepakGoswami Apologies, fixed =), unless I'm getting your question wrong!

Comment: `hide` is just an example it can be any class or css hiding div. I want to select only visible element. other classes used might not be there. See my edit to post

Comment: @DeepakGoswami I see! Well, I've included one last example; otherwise apologies!

Comment: Thanks for helping me through, but I guess nothing seems to work for me. Hard Luck of mine :(

Comment: @DeepakGoswami Well, I still don't know what we (me and the other answer) is doing wrong, what are we missing? All the solutions exclude the hidden inputs! :o

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you scan all the inner `.blk` elements of a visibile top element using each, in this case the element itself is visible, but hidden from the middle parent.

I know you won't change your `subCheck` function, bu you can simply solve the issue by checking there the visibility of the child element `.blk`.

[`Visibile selector`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) take care of the effective visibility of the element (direct or nested):

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.
>
> Elements that are not in a document are considered to be hidden;
>   jQuery does not have a way to know if they will be visible when
>   appended to a document since it depends on the applicable styles.

I think that this change will not break anything in your code.

Code:

```
function subCheck(inBlock) {
    inBlock=(inBlock==undefined)?'':inBlock;
    var ids=[];

    $(inBlock+' .blk:visible').each(function(){
        ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    //console.log(ids);
    alert(ids);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/her4Y/

Comment: I have already mentioned that I don't want to change my `subCheck` function since its being used at many places. :(

Comment: But in the other placese in your code you must check only visible elements or hidden too? The side effect is only here

Comment: Nope, these code  $(inBlock+' .blk') all the child elements (visibile or not) of the starting selector; by adding :visibile at the end, you'll get all the child VISIBLE elements

Comment: ya that code is in my function actually :), that's why I asked if I can select elements without changing it, since I have this function for various validations, I didn't put all code here since it was of no relevance with my problem.

Comment: I think that without change it you have to specify more specific selector as parameter (a:visible b:visibile c:visible), but will be worst IMHO

Comment: ya that's the problem actually, if I will add classes to each element that will be nightmare for me to do, since I have almost 10000 fields of different types (input, select, textarea, radio, etc) through out my application.

Comment: I think the only sane way is my current solution :-)

Comment: means adding :visible with my function? that would not be solution since I have added one case of mine here this would be there in my function several times with different classes of validation. :(